# If $f(x)=f(2x)$, then $f$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-equations

Suppose $f$ is continuous from $(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, and $f(x)=f(2x)$. Then, can we conclude that $f$ is differentiable and uniformly continuous?

I think yes, because, it is clear that $f(x)=f(2^kx)$ for any $x$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Also, this implies that for any $\epsilon>0$, $f(x+\epsilon)=f(x)$, for $x=\frac{\epsilon}{2^k-1}$. This implies that $f$ is constant. Hence, the differentiability and uniform continuity is trivial. any counterexamples to this? Am I right here? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You will need continuity at $x=0$ for your argument to work out (from $f(x) = f(\frac{x}{2^n})$ you take $n\to \infty$ and only if the limit on the right exists - which is the definition of continuity at $x=0$ - do you get $f(x) = f(0)$).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An example of function satisfying the given properties is $f(x)=\sin (\frac {2 \pi} {\ln 2} \ln (|x|)$. So there are non-constant continuous functions  with $f(x)=f(2x)$. The function in this example is not uniformly continuous because it does not extend to a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$. Hence uniform continuity need not be true. To show that $f$ need not be differentiable we can  take a non-differentiable continuous function on $[1,2]$ with $f(1)=f(2)$ and the extend it to the intervals $[2^{n}, 2^{n+1}]$ and $[2^{-n-1}, 2^{-n}]$ using the condition $f(x)=f(2x)$. [ This last part is a repetition of the answer by Empy2 and I am just quoting it here for completeness.

Comment: but this is very tough to think such examples , is there any other way?

Comment: I've spent days thinking in this solution, trying to figure out the exact expression of the function. The methods used for finding the solutions are not exhaustive, then. Because they cannot find *this* solution.

Answer (score 11):

Take any continuous function $f:[1,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=f(2x)$, then extend it to $(0,\infty)$.
Is it differentiable ?  Does it remain uniformly continuous near zero?

Comment: but the condition of the question says that $f(x)=f(2x)$ for all $x$ in the domain. So how does your example help in that? So by your example, I think the function should be uniform continuous right? But, I doubt differentiability. I could take function withy absolute values that satisfy your condition

Comment: @vidyarthi You can extend the function from $[1,2]$ to $[2,2^{2}]$, $[2^{2},2^{3}]$ etc using the condition $f(x)=f(2x)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so, then, I think it should be uniform continuous. But, what about differentaibility? I think there should be a counterexample

Comment: @Peter every continuous function on a compact interval is uniform continuous

Comment: @vidyarthi You are right, I forgot this.

Comment: @vidyarthi The answer above makes it clear that $f$ need not be differentiable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy where is the mistake in my argument?

Comment: @vidyarthi For a given $\epsilon>0$ you found $x$ such that $f(x+\epsilon)=f(x)$. That doesn't mean that $f$ is constant, far from it. In your reasoning $x$ is not arbitrary, it depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Your claim that $f$ must be  a constant is false. An example of a fucntion $f$ with the stated properties is $f(x) =\sin (\frac {2\pi} {\ln 2} \ln (|x|)$ for $0 <x<\infty$.  @vidyarthi

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy please write your explicit answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: @Empy2 sir how to extend this function on left I.e. to $(0,1)$?

Comment: @neelkanth Since $f(x)=f(2x)$, so $f(2x)=f(x)$, and $f(y)=f(y/2)$

Comment: @Empy2 $f(x)=f(\frac{x}{2})=\cdots= f(\frac{x}{2^n})$ so limit at zero depends on  $f$ value of $x$ . Am i right ?

Comment: It is only continuous on $(0,\infty)$ so $f(0)$ doesn't exist.  Any $x$ in the domain is different from $0$.  But any change gets steeper and steeper as you keep halving.  Any change that happens must also happen in an interval as short as you like, so it is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Empy2 thank you sir ...